# Xcode 4.0 hangs on loading project due to the corrupted repositories?

Tags: xcode, repository, freeze, corrupt-data

I was trying to commit some changes, Xcode was hang on bringing up the changed files. So I killed (Force Quite) the Xcode. Then next time when trying to bring up my project, Xcode just hangs on loading project. Firstly I thought that maybe my project file was corrupted, but it still the same behavior with my backup project file. So I guess that the default repository for my project is corrupted.

The question is - where is the location of the default repository for my project? can I "remove" it to see if Xcode can starts up properly w/o it?

Answer (score 5):

In XCode 4, you'll find the output contents for the project ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

I'm having this issue as well, intermittently with several projects.  I suspect Lion resume as at least part of the culprit as I've had some success with deleting the content at:
~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.Lion.savedState

I'm presently reinstalling Xcode to see if that clears things up.  A very Windows thing to have to do, eh?

Comment: ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.Lion.savedState This is the one that did it for me.

Comment: I was going to break my MacBook into little pieces, but your post saved it! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 3):

[Sorry for hijacking such a dated thread.]

When we stumble upon this issue (it happens a lot lately) we usually remove `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YOURPROJECT_RANDOMSTUFF` and restart Xcode.

Usually the hang comes along with Xcode using all available RAM and causing the machine to swap heavily.